# midi software synthesizer that plays wave files

Tags: audio, java, midi

I am programming an application, that uses javax.sound.midi, prepares a sequence and sends it to a synthesizer. Now I would like to play the "melody" with sounds, that I assign myself.

So I thought I would find an open-source software synthesizer where I could assign various wave files to midi instruments and then access the synthesizer software from my java program. The java program is supposed to connect its transmitter to the receiver of the synthesizer and play the melody.

However I did not find a suitable software. Could somebody hint me to such a synthesizer? Or maybe tell me, what I am actually looking for. I searched "midi software synthesizer", "midi soundbank from wave files" and the like.

It should preferably be platform independent or run on linux and os x.

Comment: If it is a .wav file, the sound is part of the file. I would be surprised if there was such a tool as you describe.

MIDI has nothing to do with sound - it is a protocol and acts much like the computer keyboard which issues a specific command to cause a specific result. (Press "A" and an "A" will appear on your screen).


Press a key ("C") on your keyboard and an interpreting module will produce a tone based on the note pressed.

Your question seems to conflate the two separate types of procedure as if they are the same.

Perhaps edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: @Xavierjazz, I am specifically looking for a MIDI synthesizer, the interpreting module in your comment. I am using the standard MIDI sequencer that is returned to me by java (MidiSystem.getSequencer()). So I am looking for an interpreting module that produces a tone based on the note pressed where the tone is an audio bitstream (e.g. a .wav file).